# filtering the most likes withcount not working

Tags: laravel

All the rest of the functionality works fine, follow and latest but for some reason it won't filter the likes. I think it is the count method, but if I do likes->count() I end up with too many queries, any solutions for this?

```php
    public function index(Request $request) {
        $search = request()->input('title');

        $posts = Post::query()->latest();

        if ($search) {
            $posts->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . request()->title. '%');
        } elseif ($request->has('likes')) {
            $posts->withCount('likes')->orderByDesc('likes_count');
            
        } elseif ($request->has('latest')) {
            $posts->orderByDesc('created_at');
        } elseif ($request->has('follow')) {
            $posts->whereIn('user_id', $request->user()->following()->pluck('users.id'));
        }

        return view('welcome', [
            'posts' => $posts->withCount(['comments', 'likes'])->paginate(12)
        ]); 
    }
```

```
Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('post_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue

```
$posts = Post::query()->latest();
```

"->latest()" is already sorting by date.
If you take it out, it should work just fine.

Comment: Where did you find loadCount? It returns undefined, why does orderbydesc work for the other filtering

Comment: sortbydesc is also undefined

Comment: It's in the documentation.  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#deferred-count-loading

Comment: What is the relationship between likes and posts. Table scheme would help

Comment: Taking a second look at your code, it looks like it should work discard the previous loadCount suggestion. What behaviour are you trying to achieve and what behaviour are you getting?

Comment: @Shanediesel are you trying to return posts that have a certain number of likes?

Comment: No, to sort post by most likes, but now nothing get's sorted at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235006/discussion-between-shanediesel-and-jonathan-ebiyomare).